# Where clause is not working properly : No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: jquery, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using spring mvc framework with postgres database and hibernate ORM.

I have face this error:

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter
>   found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList] with root
>   cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for
>   return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

**This is my Controller:**

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/ajaxmethod/getdistrict")
    public List<District> getDistrict(HttpServletRequest request){

        System.out.println("request:" + request.toString());
        String division = request.getParameter("division");
        System.out.println("division::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" + division );
        List<District> districtlist = this.upazillaService.listDistricts(division);

        return districtlist;
    }
```

**This is my DAO:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<District> listdistricts(String division) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from District where division_id=:division");
        query.setParameter("division", Integer.parseInt(division));
        System.out.println( " query::::::::::::::::::::::: " + query.toString());
        List<District> districtList = query.list();
        for (District p : districtList) {
            logger.info("district List::" + p);
        }
      //  session.clear();
        return districtList;
    }
```

**This is my model:**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "division_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Division division;
```

**This is jquery:**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
              $("#district").prop("disabled", true);

              $("#division").change(function () {
                  var division =jQuery("#division option:selected").val();
                    console.log(division);
                    $("#district").prop("disabled", false); 
                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/farmvill/ajaxmethod/getdistrict",
                     data: {division: division},
                     success: function (data) {
                        console.log("success");
                     },
                     error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                     }         
            });  
              });
        });
</script>
```

How can I avoid the error?

Comment: Your resultset doesn't properly mapped with `List<District>`. May be you should use reference to your db object `District` as a parameter when you query.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna  Can you explain describe properly with any example ? I can't understand. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is not written in a proper way. It looks like you are using hibernate to retrieve object list using id of division. Try to write the query in this way:

```
FROM District a WHERE a.division.id =:division
```

ID should be Long type

```
query.setParameter("division", Long.parseLong(division));
```

It should run exactly how you want.